# Payment Instruments Financial Accounts

Tags: civicontribute, accounting, financial-accounts

I have a client with a new In-Kind Payment Instrument and we want it to to go to their In-Kin Financial Account. This is not one of the options how/can we do this?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could let us know which version of CiviCRM you are using.  There have been some big changes in recent versions.

Comment: I am on the newest release of 4.6

Answer (score 1):

Go to Administer->CiviContribute->Financial Accounts and click on Add Financial Account. You will also need to go to Administer->CiviContribute->Financial Types and set up an In-Kind Financial type to use with your Financial Account.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you are looking to set up a new financial type and accounting code.

If so, I suggest that you read this chapter of the book: [Contributions - Set up](https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/contributions/setup/)

Comment: I am trying to use a specific account that I created for a financial instrument.  Right now there is a very limited drop down.

Comment: @Josh I'm not clear what you mean.  Could you please explain what you want to do in more detail?

Comment: If you go to Admin ->  CiviContribute ->  Payment Instruments.  You have a to select a financial account.  I want to select a financial account others than those that are defined in the existing drop down list.